# Родительский класс , что не так делаю

Tags: python, классы

Создать родительский класс auto, у которого есть атрибуты:
brand, age, cоlor, mark и weight.
А так же методы: move, birthday и stop.
Методы move и stop выводят сообщение на экран «move» и «stop»,а birthday увеличивает атрибут age на 1.
Атрибуты brand, age и mark являются обязательными при объявлении объекта.
Вот код

```
class auto:
    brand = 'audi'
    age = 5
    color = 'red'
    mark = 'a8'
    weight = 5000

    def __init__(self, brand, age, mark):
        self.brand = brand
        self.age = age
        self.mark = mark

    def move(self):
        print(self.brand, self.mark, 'move')

    def birthday(self):
        for item in age(self.age + 1):
            print(item)

    def stop(self):
        print(self.brand, self.mark, 'stop')


a = auto('opel', 5, 'vectra')
a.move()
a.birthday()
a.stop()
```

Comment: `for item in age(self.age + 1):` - age не список, просто увеличьте его на единицу `self.age += 1`

Comment: а остальное правильно ?  а то не уверен

Comment: на первый взгляд, да